# .place_forget() not executed until after everything else in the function

Tags: python, tkinter, time, widget

So I have the below function that should forget a button, iterate a score, wait one second, and bring the button back.

```
def iteration():
    global score
    #should hide button
    b1.place_forget()
    #raise score
    score += 1
    label.config(text = score)
    #wait one second
    sleep(1)
    #bring button back
    b1.place(relx = 0.3, y = 30)
```

Instead, the place_forget() does not run until after everything else, resulting in the button never blinking and waiting a second before iterating the score. Why are things happening in this order and how can I fix it? Here is the rest of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

global score
score = 0

def iteration():
    global score
    #should hide button
    b1.place_forget()
    #raise score
    score += 1
    label.config(text = score)
    #wait one second
    sleep(1)
    #bring button back
    b1.place(relx = 0.3, y = 30)
    
 
root = Tk()  
root.geometry("150x100") 


#make label
label = Label(root, text = score) 
  
# place in the window 
label.place(relx=0.4, y=5) 
  
#make and place button 1
b1 = Button(root, text = "hide text", 
            command = lambda: iteration())
  
b1.place(relx = 0.3, y = 30) 
  
# make and place button 2
b2 = Button(root, text = "retrieve text", 
            command = lambda: iteration())
  
b2.place(relx = 0.3, y = 50) 
  
# Start the GUI 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For your case, you need to call `root.update()` before `sleep(1)` to force tkinter to update the window.

Comment: Would appreciate marking the answer as the correct one

Answer (score 1):

I think the process is happening but your `sleep(1)` is freezing the GUI and hence you cannot see it.

1. Either, replace `sleep(1)` and then place the widget with `after()`, might get your desired effect, like:

```
def iteration():
    global score
    #should hide button
    b1.place_forget()
    #raise score
    score += 1
    label.config(text = score)
    #wait one second and bring button back
    root.after(1000,lambda: b1.place(relx = 0.3, y = 30))
```

`after()` prevents the GUI from lagging for one second where it is supposed to be hiding and showing.

2. Or else, use `threading` like:

```
import threading
.... #same old codes

b1 = Button(root, text = "hide text",command =lambda: threading.Thread(target=iteration).start())
```

Now the `sleep(1)` does not cause GUI to lag as it is not in the tkinter thread.

3. Or else, you can get it to work with `update()` but the GUI still might be frozen but it updates, the button "blinking", like:

```
root.update()
sleep(1)
#bring button back
b1.place(relx = 0.3, y = 30)
```